# Aws Error Could not load credentials from any providers

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-sts

I have a node service, which creates temporary AWS credentials using sts.assumeRole(params). If I set the accessKeyId,secretAccessKey,region in the environment. Credentials are generated successfully. If I store them in Mongo and read them. I get the following error.

**Errors**

```
Error Could not load credentials from any providers

Error region is missing
```

**Code**

```
const params = {
        RoleArn: `arn:aws:iam::${db.awsAccountId}:role/${db.awsRole}`,
        RoleSessionName: `Assumed-${db.awsRole}-Role-${timestamp}`,
        accessKeyId: db.accessId,
        secretAccessKey: db.accessToken,
        region: db.awsRegion,
      };

sts.assumeRole(params, (err, data) => {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(data);
});
```

I don't understand, following the same procedure. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setting the AWS credentials for the STS service incorrectly. You should have a look [at the user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html) for the full explanation.

There are multiple ways to set credentials, so pick the one that works best in your situation. When you were using environment variables, they were picked up automatically, but if you're reading them from some other place, you'll have to create a `Credentials` object and add it to the `AWS.config` manually.

More info on the `Credentials` object can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Config.html#credentials-property) and on the `AWS.config` [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Credentials.html).